# Debug the results of method calls without adding intermediate lines of code

Tags: debugging, visual-c++

I'm trying to be more efficient with my debugging sessions. **Is there a way to see the results of expressions as implicit locals?**

In this contrived example, I'd want to know what cs.method2() evaluated to without having to write a line of code or stepping into that method.

```
bool myObject::isEmpty(double d)
{
     bool res;
     custString cs(d);

     // bool dresult = cs.method2();
     res = !cs.method1().empty() && cs.method2();

     return res; //set break here.
}
```

I don't want to step into method2 because it's a deep chain and I'm only interested in the result, but that is always passed to a return like

```
return _mycs_string(_dat);
```

So then I have to step all the way into that call which may have the same pattern.

And I'd like to not have to write code splitting up lines since this is a library that I have no intention of modifying.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>My advice would be to write the code much as you have it here, explicitly setting the result of cs.method2() in the previous line.</strike>

The reason for this suggestion is that I have great faith in compiler developers being able to optimize away the 'unnecessary' local variable before returning from the function.

(You can look at the result code from the compiler for the code you have here, see what it does with your `res' variable)

The other possibility is to wWatch the stack (in the debugger) on return from the cs.method2() call as that's where your return value is stored.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you are suggesting? If I'm stepping out (f10) through myObject::isEmpty(d), what am I watching? I don't want to have to step into anything below this method if I don't have to.

Comment: Each debugger will be different, but you should be able to view the stack prior to the return from cs.method2(), that's where your return value is stored.  Write your own function that returns an int (for example) and then watch the stack window prior to the return.

Comment: If you don't mind using windbg, you could set a breakpoint on custString::method2(). When that breakpoint is hit, issue `gu` which will run to the function's return address. You could then issue `r eax` which will hold the return value. If 64 bit, then `r rax` will show the return value.

Comment: You might be on the right track. There has to be a vs equivalent.